# Polaroid photo gallery effect with background images/css

Tags: photo-gallery

I'm showing photos and photo albums on the same page and would like to create a "polaroid" style effect for the photo albums, see [image: example].

I'm looking for a background graphic or some css to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this website:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PolaroidPhotobarGallery/

I think it's best to search for jQuery version as there are plenty of tutorial when you Google it.